# setup of flutter in vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, installation, flutter-doctor

```
flutter : The term 'flutter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ flutter doctor
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (flutter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

this is the error which is showing up again and again
solution of this error

Comment: check this : https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

Answer (score 0):

Add flutter sdk path to environment variable.
like C:/flutter/bin